# How to map and use Bundle Identifier and Bundle Suffix?

Tags: iphone, ios5, bundle

I am about to release my first App for review. There are two items I am not able to understand -

1. Bundle Identifier
2. Bundle Suffix

In .plist file I can see three things -

1. Bundle display name : ${PRODUCT_NAME}
2. Bundle identifier : companyname.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
3. Bundle name : ${PRODUCT_NAME}
4. and in Project->Build Settings->Product Name

---

Now if my Company Name: "ABC Organization"; App Name: "XYZ Application". What should be the setting for each 1, 2, 3, 4 above.

I have searched the forum with answers but not able to find direct mapping - so not able to understand and need help to release my App for review (Thou when I put "XYZ Application" in "Project->Build Settings->Product Name" - my App name gets updated perfectly fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now if my Company Name: "ABC Organization"; App Name: "XYZ Application". What should be the setting for each 1, 2, 3, 4 above.

1. Bundle identifier : com.abcorganization.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
2. Project->Build Settings->Product Name  == XYZApplication
3. Bundle display name == XYZ Application

The Product Name is the fundamental piece of information that you are expected to provide.

The Product Name will determine the name assigned to your bundle (the file containing your app): this is known as the "bundle name" and it is the "low-lovel" file name.

Besides the bundle name, you have the chance to specify a "bundle display name", which is the name that will be displayed for your app on the device and that is useful in certain cases.

Say, e.g., that you want your app to be called "app:XYZ" -- you will not be allowed to use the ":" within the bundle name (not allowed character according to the file system conventions), so you could define "appXYZ" as a bundle name and "app:XYZ" as display bundle name.

Finally, the Bundle identifier is the unique name of your app by which it will be identified on the App Store and that is also used to associate a profile (distribution or development to your app).

The Bundle Identifier is expected to match the App ID suffix you specify in iTunes Connect when creating an app.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Sergio. Does that means - I should not change "Bundle display name", "Bundle name" and anything else in "Bundle identifier" ? Also while submitting my App, Apple asks for Bundle Identifier and Bundle Suffix - what should be the value for those (if we take the same Company and App Name) ?

Comment: See also my edit for more info. When you create an app, you specify an app ID suffix: this should be the same as your bundle identifier: com.abcorganization.XYZApplication

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize fully you were using a blank space in your app name -- check my edited answer: you should also specify a bundle display name...

Comment: Ok, got it. So finally -

Bundle identifier: "com.abcorganization.XYZApplication"
Bundle display name: "XYZ Application"
Bundle name: "XYZApplication"
Bundle Suffix: "com.abcorganization.XYZApplication"

Project->Build Settings->Product Name: "XYZApplication"

Comment: Good answer, one small suggestion: I recommend replacing the `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` incantation and writing the bundle identifier directly into the property list. It reduces the chance for surprises.

Comment: @benzado agreed. Your bundle id should always be explicit. Drop the `rfc1034identifier` crap and put in whatever your distribution provisioning profile specifies.